# question about the Darboux integral theorem proof

Tags: calculus, integration, proof-writing

well, the sentence goes like this:

Consider $f$ bounded function in $[a,b]$. 
$f$ is integrable IF AND ONLY IF $\forall\epsilon >0$ $\exists$  a partition $P$ of $\left[a,b\right]$ such that $U\left(f,P\right)-L\left(f,P\right)<\epsilon$

I solved the first side of the proof ($\Rightarrow $) , but i struggle in the $\Leftarrow$ side. can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Set $U = \inf_P U(f, P)$ and $L = \sup_P L(f, P)$, where $P$ runs over the set of partitions of $[a, b]$. Clearly $U \geq L$. For each $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a partition $P$ with $U(f, P) - L(f, P) < \epsilon$. Hence
$$U \leq U(f, P) < L(f, P) + \epsilon \leq L + \epsilon.$$
Since $\epsilon > 0$ is arbitrary, it follows that $U = L$, which is exactly the condition for $f$ to be Darboux integrable.